# Web based software to create searchable document database with user management

Tags: document-management, document-indexing

I am looking for a web based solution that allows me to run a web based database for (mostly) PDF documents (plus maybe a few MS Office documents). I've googled for "document management" (and for lack of a better tag tagged this question accordingly) but that's not it, as I do not need most of the features that are usually implied by the term document management system - to wit there is no need for collaboration, calendars, versioning, workflows etc.  Rather I need something that builds a very good search index from the documents to allow authenticated users to find and download relevant information.

To give a short list of what I'm looking for:

- completely web based solution
- something with long term support
- integrated user management (access only for authenticated users)
- must support 1000+ users ("users" means people who search the database, plus maybe a few dozen people who upload documents)
- commercial software/licence costs is okay (budget for running expenses is in the upper thousands/year. We're aware that there will be additional cost for implementation )
- we start with some 1000 documents (as archives will not be migrated from the current database), documents will be added a rate of about 1000 per year
- some of the documents contain sensitive information, so we are looking for something with a good record regarding security
- software must be able to index pdf documents as well as allow manually added metadata
- we must be able to sort documents into topics and give access rights based on topic (search should return only documents which the user has permission to access/download)
- should use a template system that allows our frontend developers to integrate our CI (plus should allow for a responsive/mobile-friendly layout)
- users should be able to save their searches and should be notified if a newly indexed document matches a saved search
- simply structured search result page with a very good fulltext search that displays title and excerpt from the documents

The last bullet point is rather important to us - we run a survey in the current incarnation of the database and received endless variations of "I want a simple Google-like interface with a single text field, additional search filters should be a last resort and not something I have to use regularly". However it seems that pre-built packages usually offer more of a portal-like / intranet structure. In the past we have build similar solutions on top of open source packages (Drupal etc.) but our experience w/r/t security and long term support have been mixed a least so we'd prefer to buy something with a proven track record (if that is the right expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alfresco is probably the best for this scenario.

[image: Alfresco Share search excerpts]

- Completely web based: Yes, either SaaS or on your company's own server. Additional protocols like CMIS are also available should you need them.
- Long-term support up to 5 years, available directly from the Alfresco company or from [third-parties](http://orderofthebee.org/professionals/)
- Integrated user management (access only for authenticated users): Yes
- Alfresco is used for huge projects, for instance I know a project with 100,000 users.
- Open source, pay for support
- A million document is not a problem
- Great security record, patches are available very quickly. A solution based on Alfresco has been certified Department of Defense 5015
- Indexes PDF documents and many other file types, you can define your own metadata schema and edit metadata via the web interface
- You can organize documents into folders, and give access rights based on folder. Search will return only documents which the user has permission to download
- You can develop [new themes](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/themes-create.html)
- The web UI is not especially mobile-friendly, but there is an app that allows you to do what you want in a native mobile experience
- Users can [save their searches](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/customize-savedsearch.html). New results will appear on their dashboard.
- Search result pages show extracts around matches if you use [this patch](http://aymen-s.blogspot.jp/2011/03/implementing-search-hits-highlight-in.html), it is not very easy to set up but it is doable.

Alfresco is used by many big companies who handle a lot of documents and can't tolerate any security failure: http://www.alfresco.com/customers

Comment: +1 for a very good answer (especially since our "mobile" requirement evaporated during the last meeting). I'll wait for a few days (and get informed about Alfresco) and if nothing even more interesting turns up Ill accept. Thank you!